# ¿Por qué no esta funcionando el responsive del bootstrap de mi web?

Tags: html, bootstrap, responsive

Es un ejercicio para clase, el caso es que aparentemente está todo bien, el responsive no funciona, uso Bootstrap 4.
Como tengo la web en servidor local (Xampp), puedo ver la web desde el móvil, pero se ve igual que en el PC, no está funcionando el responsive, os dejo el código.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<link href="css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
 </head>
 <body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed aside-menu- 
 hidden">
<header  class="app-header navbar">

        <div class="w-100 cabecera">
            <img class="logo" src="./img/kawasaki-logo.png" height="35px;">
        </div>
        <div class="w-100 bar">
        </div>

</header>


<div class="container">
    <div class="col-12 marco">
        <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
        <p class="subtitle">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae 
            quam dolores distinctio molestias dolore in similique a 
            spernatur, voluptatibus consequuntur ipsum vero doloremque qui 
            aliquam ut laboriosam adipisci sit tempore vitae tenetur facere 
            perspiciatis voluptates molestiae.
        </p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label class="switch switch-default switch-pill switch- 
                 secondary-outline">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked="">
                    <span class="switch-label"></span>
                    <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                <p class="subtitle">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
                    elit. Beatae quam dolores distinctio molestias dolore in 
                    similique aspernatur, voluptatibus consequuntur ipsum 
                    vero doloremque qui aliquam 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label class="switch switch-default switch-pill switch- 
                 secondary-outline">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked="">
                    <span class="switch-label"></span>
                    <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                <p class="subtitle">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
                    elit. Beatae quam dolores distinctio molestias dolore in 
                    similique aspernatur, voluptatibus consequuntur ipsum 
                    vero doloremque qui aliquam 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <label class="switch switch-default switch-pill switch- 
                secondary-outline">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="switch-input" checked="">
                    <span class="switch-label"></span>
                    <span class="switch-handle"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <h2 class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
                <p class="subtitle">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing 
                    elit. Beatae quam dolores distinctio molestias dolore in 
                    similique aspernatur, 
                    voluptatibus consequuntur ipsum vero doloremque qui 
                    aliquam 
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row final">
            <div class="col-9"></div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn- 
                    success">Success</button>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<footer>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3 f1">
            Siguenos
        </div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3"></div>
        <div class="col-6 social">
            <img src="./img/faceb.png" alt="">
            <img src="./img/twitt.png" alt="">
            <img src="./img/insta.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-3"></div>
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.css**

```
    .cabecera{
             background-color: black;


   }

   .bar{
        background-image: url(../img/header-bg.gif);
        height: 20px;

     }

   .navbar{
            padding: 0;
   }

  body{
       background-image: url(../img/kawa.jpg);
       background-size:cover;


  }

  .marco{
         background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
         text-align: center;
         border-radius: 20px;
         padding: 30px;
  }

 .title{
        text-align: justify;
        color: #f1f490;

 }

  .subtitle{
            color: white;
            text-align: left;
 } 

.logo{
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-left: 50px;
} 
.f1{
   color: white;
   padding-bottom: 20px;
   text-align: left;
}

footer{
      padding-top: 40px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.social{
       text-align: center;
 }

.container{

            margin-top: 150px;

}
```

**Solución**

me faltaba poner este meta:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: ¿És style.min.css el estilo de bootstrap o uno tuyo?

Comment: No veo donde colocas la referencia a la hoja de estilos de bootstrap

Comment: si esa hoja de estilos es la de bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

En la parte de tu código donde haces los imports solo tienes JQuery y el JavaScript de Bootstrap, te falta el CSS.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

El CSS debería tener un aspecto tipo:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Si aún así sigue sin funcionar puedes probar a hacer los imports de esta manera:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: no, no falta, es el style.min.css ya esta solucionado muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @sergipc88. Me alegra que tu problema esté solucionado. Te recomiendo que en vez de añadir la solución editando la pregunta lo hagas como respuesta a tu propia pregunta, para que si alguien tiene el mismo problema pueda encontrar la solución rápidamente.

Comment: de acuerdo, es que una vez lo hice como tu me recomiendas, pero, alguien me dijo que borrara la respuesta y lo pusiera en la pregunta, en que quedamos? jejejeje

Comment: @sergipc88 Te recomiendo leer: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer si tienes dudas sobre responderse a uno mismo. :)